# How to add next and previous buttons to a light-box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code to develop my light-box where i need my prev and next buttons work accordingly.I have break down the code till this far. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

```
$(function () {
    $('.thumbnail li').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('.light-box li:eq(' + index + ')').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/ts2jku2x/6/)**

Comment: Any fiddle to startup i struck there

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
$(function () {
    var currentIndex = 0,
        lightboxLis = $(".light-box li");

    $('.thumbnail li').click(function () {
        currentIndex = $(this).index();
        lightboxLis.hide();
        lightboxLis.eq(currentIndex).show();

        //put next prev show here otherwise it won't work due to your hover
        //when you hover the next prev button in your old version you no longer hover the li so can't click on the button
        $('.next, .prev').show();

        //add the hide of next prev to when you close the lightbox
    });

    $('.next').click(function() {
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex == lightboxLis.length) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }

        lightboxLis.hide();
        lightboxLis.eq(currentIndex).show();        
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
        currentIndex--;
        if (currentIndex < 0) {
            currentIndex = lightboxLis.length - 1;
        }

        lightboxLis.hide();
        lightboxLis.eq(currentIndex).show();        
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ts2jku2x/8/)

Comment: Thanks @Pete thats what Im looking for :)